# JS (ES6) JSON-Serializable solution for 2D-Map with negative indices?

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, ecmascript-6

I have a 2D grid of objects, and I need to store it in a way that allows json (de)serialization while keeping the indices. I could use 2D-Vectors as indices for a Map, but this is not serializable (Map object). I can't use arrays with negative indices because they will not serialize negative keys, and I can't use objects, since they don't allow for integer keys. Any ideas how this could be solvable without a custom (de)serializer ? Or is there no way around it ?

Comment: you can use integer keys with objects. the only drawback would be manually casting to a Number when _adding_ indices (subtract/div/mult still work). you can also use a callback to stringify and a reviver with parse.

Comment: @dandavis is correct The only "caveat" is that you need to use quotes when making the object as a literal `var obj = { "-1" : "hello" }` or brackets notation to assign/retrieve values from negative integer keys `obj["-1"] //"hello"` `obj["-2"] = "world"`